# Formatting a Google Sheet to Judge auditions

Tags: google-apps-script

I need suggestions on formulas and formatting to set up a sheet to judge an all district orchestra audition.  Data will be input with the use of Google Forms.  There will be students auditioning on four different instruments, (Violin, Viola, Cello, Bass) each set of students will be judged by 2 different judges.  We need to total the 2 judges' scores for each student and then sort the students by highest to lowest combined scores within each instrument group.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the data for each student is in column A,B,C and D..Then for column E where you'd want to have the sum for each row of these 4 data values, use the formula `=SUM(Ai,Bi,Ci,Di)` where **i** is the row number.
Do it for the first row like **(A1,B1,C1,D1)**.

After you do it for the first row, just select the cell and drag vertically until the end.

After this you can just *right-click* on the cloumn E's heading at the top, and slect ***Sort Z-A*** for sorting it in descending order.